# Submit another response missing from Google Form

Tags: google-forms

If I create a new Google Form, and leave the "Limit to 1 response" option unchecked:

[image]

At the end of the form, the user will see a "Submit another response" link:

[image]

However, I have an existing Google Form where that entry is always missing no matter what settings I try to enable/disable (e.g. "Collect email addresses", "Limit to 1 response", "Edit after submit", etc.):

[image]

How do I get the "Submit another response" link to show up?

Answer (score 1):

**To show the "Submit another response" link at the end of a form:**

1. Ensure GENERAL > "Limit to 1 response" is unchecked.
2. Ensure PRESENTATION > "Show link to submit another response" is checked.

---

Here is what that setting looks like in the "Presentation" tab:

[image]